# How does a cache miss EXACTLY occur?

Tags: caching, cpu, cache-control

I'm trying to understand how exactly a cache miss occurs. So far this is the way I understand it:
CPU requests for address x, searches its own (L1/L2) cache for it. If it is not there then it's a cache miss.
Now what is missing here is how exactly does it find out that the information is not available in cache? What information do cache lines reserve? So far I know a cache line should contain this information:

```
Address of the information, Data within that address.
```

Having this information CPU can find out whether an address is available in its cache or not. The problem arises when, it has an invalid copy of data. So my question would be:
How does the processor find out if some data is valid or invalid?
Are there flags stored in each cache line? Does it ask the protocol for this information? If so, where are protocol's information kept(Cache/Memory/Elsewhere)?
I'm still searching, but I'd appreciate any resources on this.

**--EDIT**
Similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7718895/279982), yet no answer. There doesn't seem to be any detailed information of MESI protocol. Any help is appreciated.

**--EDIT2**
I found more info in [MESI CMP Directory](http://gem5.org/Cache_Coherence_Protocols#MESI_CMP_directory). It states that "L2 cache controller on-chip directory is co-located with the corresponding cache blocks in L2 Cache", but nothing about where L1 cache controller information resides.

Comment: Does Wikipedia [MESI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol) and the references not provide enough infos on the subject?

Comment: @A.H.: No, already checked. If you look you'd see that it's about a paragraph or two.

Comment: @AtoMerZ check this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cache line (L1 or L2) contains the following information:

```
dirty_bit | many_memory_word
```

When the **dirty bit** contains 1 that means the line cache is not similar to the correspondent in the RAM. When it contains 0 that means the line cache contains the exact copy of the memory line actually in the RAM.

When the CPU request an address in the RAM, a translation is made using the MTL to have a correspondent line cache address which is supposed to contain the information.

If there is no address found, that means the information is not on the cache line and then a cache miss happens. If an address on the cache is found, then if the **dirty bit** of the line requested in the cache is set to 1, a cache miss will happen, and the information actually in the line cache will be written back in memory. The address of the line in the cache makes the CPU know which address corresponds in the real memory RAM.

So when the CPU requesst an information from memory, this information (and more) are put on the line cache, and the **dirty bit** is set to 0 that means that the cache line represents the exact copy of memory line in the RAM.

Then, when writing operations occur in the line cache, the CPU sets the **dirty bit** to 1 that means the line does no longer represent the copy actually present in the RAM. So if a reading operation occurs on an address in the cache whose **dirty bit** is set to 1, a cache miss happens.

**Reference:** have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) for more.

Comment: Thanks you FOPA. Are there any references on this that back you up? I need to be sure this is the way it works.

Comment: Accepted. Please add the link to your answer as a reference.